# Broken Links in different browsers

Tags: wordpress, browsers, internet-explorer-7

Hi I'm having problems with our website, http://www.accessiblehomehealthcare.com, which is a wordpress 2.7 (version).  All of a sudden our RSS links broke on the right side, which has happened before and I fixed it within 5 mins.  Now, when I fix it, it doesn't look right in different version of I.E. or Firefox, I have I.E. 8 and Firefox 3.6.15 and it looks good for the most part, but there are a few parts where the links are broken.  One browser the links would look ok but go to another page and the links or logos would be broken. Certain parts of the website should be static(identical) to the other pages of the site, but if a link is broken on one page, its perfect on another page.

I was wondering was there a secret code for wordpress to keep the sites compatible with all browser versions  or is there a bigger issue????

Any help or suggestions will help???

Comment: Hi, can you give us the url to a page that is working and one that isn't? I have tried 3 now and they all work.

Comment: Hi, the firefox 3.3616 http://www.accessiblehomehealthcare.com/franchising/ shows up perfect and so does Internet(I.E.) 8, with no broken links. Go to the same page but in I.E. 6,7,8,9 or firefox 3.6,3.0. I.E. 7 there are links showing up broken on the bottom of our home page that shouldn't even be on our site.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have some old information in your browser cache. Make sure you have completely cleared out all the caches from your browser before you begin testing. This way you are likely to see the same thing in every browser.